# How to connect Spring boot with Elasticsearch 7.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am using Elasticsearch 7.3 and unable to connect it to my Spring boot application in order to use `ElasticsearchRepository`.

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig {
    @Value("${elasticsearch.host:localhost}")
    public String host;
    @Value("${elasticsearch.port:9300}")
    public int port;

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    private int timeout = 60;

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        System.out.println("host:" + host + "port:" + port);
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "changeme"));
        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")).setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
        builder.setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000).setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(0));

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
        return client;
    }



}
```

These are the dependencies that I have

> compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport', version: '7.7.1'
>
> compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '7.7.1'
>
> compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '4.0.1.RELEASE'

**Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchClientHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/GenericAction
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.callInitializers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.configure(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.initialize(JettyWebServer.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.<init>(JettyWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getJettyWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203)
    at com.techno.homes.search.SearchApplication.main(SearchApplication.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchClientHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/GenericAction
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchClientHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/GenericAction
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:149)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$750b9056.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$750b9056$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$968598cb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$750b9056.servletEndpointRegistrar(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchClientHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/GenericAction
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchClientHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/GenericAction
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchClientHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/GenericAction
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:590)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans.get(HealthIndicatorRegistryBeans.java:42)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.healthIndicatorRegistry(HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c859543b.CGLIB$healthIndicatorRegistry$2(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c859543b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6e2fc625.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c859543b.healthIndicatorRegistry(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/GenericAction
```

But it is not running.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Please provide error in console

Comment: Please make sure `elasticsearch` dependency and your client and server both have the same version.

Comment: @sonus21 questions updated.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati please check updated Qs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the pom.xml dependency section related to Elaticsearch dependencies and code which I use to initialize the client.

**Pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**And client initilzation code**

```
@Configuration
@Primary
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    /**
     * Creates a Elasticsearch client from config
     *
     * @return Elasticsearch client
     */
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9500, "http")));
        return client;
    }
}
```

And my `application properties`

```
elasticsearch.host=localhost
elasticsearch.port=9500
```

Answer (score 10):

You are using Spring Boot, there is no need to write own `Configuration` class - you can use advantages of autoconfiguration.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

It's working for elasticsearch too, see
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.html

Just add to your application properties this lines

```
spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=http://localhost:9300
spring.elasticsearch.rest.username=elastic
spring.elasticsearch.rest.password=changeme
```

Besides that, I am sure you have some mess in your dependencies, try to remove it and use just this

> compile group 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:2.3.0.RELEASE'

Answer (score 1):

AT the time of configuring Elasticsearch in our application, we need to define how we connect to the Elasticsearch instance.You can try the  RestHighLevelClient  like that -

```
@Configuration
    @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.your.repo.package")
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.your.package" })
    public class Config {

        @Bean
        public RestHighLevelClient client() {
            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration 
                = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                    .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                    .build();

            return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
        }

        @Bean
        public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
            return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved by adding following dependencies.

```
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '7.7.1'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '7.7.1'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-client', version: '7.7.1'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport', version: '7.7.1'
```